# Devise Strong Parameters when trying to update user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to move from the account update page and submit it. I think i am having problems with devise and this submitting. I have tried a few things in the application controller but have not had any joy. Also i have read through the devise docs but this hasnt worked for me either. The error i am getting is the following: 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Current password can't be blank
This is the case when i have input the users current password? I have included the errors from my terminal and also the code from my application controller.

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DVVUgIGna8TZwJTBU/ghNT7PTcO/CERC0JXUUQWOW/o=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Emma", "email"=>"n@m.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "line1"=>"", "line2"=>"", "town"=>"", "county"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "organization"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update"}
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 21  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
      User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
    Unpermitted parameters: email, password, password_confirmation, current_password, organization






  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode)}
  end

 private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path(current_user) #basically whichever path you think meets your needs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated with the following and solved this

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode, :password, :password_confrimation, :current_password)}
```